# cannot add a custom wiki page to a wiki library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, contenttype

i created custom content type with some publishing content type.
then i created a page layout based on the custom content type.
then i created a wikipage library and enabled the management of content types in general settings then added the custom content type to this library and set as the default type.Now when i come to library and click the new document button in the ribbon i can see the custom content type in the drop down.But on clicking it showing an error.

> Some files can harm your computer.If the file information below looks suspicious, or you do not fully trust the source,do not open the file.

So i click ok then a new popup comes with this message.

> The document could not be created
>   The required application may not be installed properly, or the template for this document library cannot be opened.
>   Please try the following:
>   1.Check the general settingsfor this document libraryfor the name of the template,and install the application neccessary for opening the template.If the application was set to install on first use, run the application and then try creating a new document again.
>   2.If you have permission to modify this document library, go to general settings for the library and configure a new template.

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found the  [following link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833714)

The last option of this link worked for me.

i.e. Repairing office. It is an environmental issue.